# table with rowspan and colspan

Tags: html, css, html-table

can somebody explain that how does this `colspan` and `rowspan` system works, i have made this with `rowspan="4"` but it looks like it is actually 3 and not 4 i mean the result, and why are '55577855' and 'ikä' are on right side, shoudn't those two be under 'henkilöstöt' ? i have tried many times.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
table, th, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
th, td {
    padding: 5px;
    text-align: left;    
}
</style>
</head>
<body>


<table >
 
<tr>
  <th rowspan="4">Henkilöstöt</th>
  <th colspan="3">koulutus</th>
</tr>
<tr>
 <th rowspan="3">Muu</th>
 <th rowspan="3">Ammattiiiii</th>
 <th rowspan="3">korkeakoulu</th>
</tr>
  
   <tr>
    <th >55577855</th>
  </tr>
   <tr>
    <th>ikä</th>   

  </tr>

</table>
   

  

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The [HTML specification has examples of how these attributes work](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/tables.html#table-examples)...

Comment: among other things, you don't have any regular table cells (`td`), but only header cells (`th`) , which for sure isn't valid HTML...

Comment: @Johannes Could you correct that so i could learn from it, it should look same but '55577855 ' and 'ikä' should be under 'henkilöstöt'

Answer (score 1):

The rowspan and colspan are attributes of   tag how could you use that with tr and th

You should try to use the colspan and rowspan with td

Comment: Could you correct that,  it should look same but '55577855
' and 'ikä' should be under 'henkilöstöt'

Comment: sure, wait for a moment i will post you the code

Answer (score 1):

maybe, this will help you..

```
    <table border ="1">

<tr>
  <th>Henkilöstöt</th>
  <th>koulutus</th>
</tr>

  <tr>
<td >Muu</th>
 <td >Ammattiiiii</td>
 <td >korkeakoulu</td>
</tr>
   <tr>
    <td>55577855</td>
  </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>ikä</td>   


  </tr>



</table>
```

Comment: it doesnt look the same, check it

Comment: @waleedd32 sorry posted wrong code i will edit it, wait

Comment: and why does '55577855' and 'ikä' are on right side, shoudnt those two be under 'henkilöstöt' ?, this problem @waleedd32 is solved

Comment: @Shubnam Kumar, yeah but others should look same as mine

Comment: @waleedd32 i have updated the code check it

Comment: @Shubnam Kumar no it doesnt look the same

Comment: @waleedd32 let me try once again

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to guess what you really want (you should have supplied a graphic of he desired output), but if you want the last two table rows to go *under*  the other ones, you have to insert two empty rows to make up for the `rowspan`s in the first row.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    table {
      border-collapse: collapse;
    }
    
    th,
    td {
      border: 1px solid black;
      padding: 5px;
      text-align: left;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>


  <table>

    <tr>
      <th rowspan="4">Henkilöstöt</th>
      <th colspan="3">koulutus</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="3">Muu</td>
      <td rowspan="3">Ammattiiiii</td>
      <td rowspan="3">korkeakoulu</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td colspan="4">55577855</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="4">ikä</td>
    </tr>

  </table>




</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Rowspan makes an element extend down into the next row.

You have four rows:

- Henkilöstöt, koulutus
- Muu, Ammattiiiii, korkeakoulu
- 55577855
- ikä

When you tell the second row to extend three rows down, you aren't telling it to become three times as large, you're telling it to appear on the same row as the third and fourth row. The third and fourth row keep their data cells and push them to the first available location.

You should either stick two empty rows after the korkeakoulu row, or you should reduce the values of all of your rowspans by 2.

EDIT

```
<tr>
  <th rowspan="2">Henkilöstöt</th>
  <th colspan="3">koulutus</th></tr>
<tr>
 <td>Muu</td>
 <td>Ammattiiiii</td>
 <td>korkeakoulu</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td >55577855</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>ikä</td>   

</tr>

</table>
```

Or you can use:

```
<table>
<tr>
  <th rowspan="4">Henkilöstöt</th>
  <th colspan="3">koulutus</th>
</tr>
<tr>
 <th rowspan="3">Muu</th>
 <th rowspan="3">Ammattiiiii</th>
 <th rowspan="3">korkeakoulu</th>
</tr>
<tr></tr>
<tr></tr>
   <tr>
    <th >55577855</th>
  </tr>
   <tr>
    <th>ikä</th>   

  </tr>

</table>
```